# slick.js plus foundation equalizer issue

Tags: html, zurb-foundation, slick.js

I have a `<section>` next to an `<aside>`. I have added a slick.js slider with a nav slider underneath within that `<section>` and have text in the `<aside>`.

In order to get the `<section>` and `<aside>` to match in height I have used zurb foundation's `data-equalizer` This all works as you load the page, however once you resize the page to mobile size and then back again to desktop size, the `data-equalizer` fails to recognise the height of the slider and so matches the height of the text in the `<aside>`.

This especially happens if you resize the window quickly and also happens without fail when you rotate a tablet device.

[Here is the example on JSFiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/garyvoss/zbogqusp/)

Any ideas of how to fix this issue would be great,
Cheers.

Comment: I'm having a similar, odd interaction between equalizer and slick; if I ever solve it I'll post here.

Comment: I know it's old but I'm having the same issue... did you find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Change : " data-equalizer-mq " for " data-equalize-on="medium" " on the first line.